# Pull list of content-type for display

Tags: drupal-7

New to Drupal, using 7.65 & can't update.

I've created a custom content type. I need to pull these through to the homepage and the loop through each to setup the formatting and display them on screen.

I thought this would be done with `pager_query`, but that's breaking the page.  How do I pull the results to then loop?

Comment: What did you try ? some code to share ?

Comment: no, I can't figure out where to start really.

Comment: You can customize tpl with using page--front.tpl.php

Comment: create a block view showing the list of content and place it where ever you want. Then you can format each element in your view.